# Google Closure using ES5 strict mode even though I specified non-strict mode (in minify-maven-plugin configuration)

Tags: minify, google-closure-compiler, strict

I'm using the [com.samaxes.maven minify-maven-plugin](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/) to minify a collection of JS source files written using some of the ES6 features Google Closure supports. Here's the relevant configuration in my POM:

```
<!-- minify-maven-plugin: Minification using Google Closure -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Creation of the common-[version].js file -->
        <execution>
            <id>common-minify</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <jsSourceDir>.</jsSourceDir>
                <jsSourceFiles>
                    ...
                </jsSourceFiles>
                <jsFinalFile>./js/common-${project.version}.js</jsFinalFile>
                <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                <closureLanguageIn>ECMASCRIPT6</closureLanguageIn>
                <closureLanguageOut>ECMASCRIPT5</closureLanguageOut>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <!-- 2 other similarly configured executions are here. -->
        ...

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is, when I run the maven goal this configuration, I get the following error message:

```
[INFO] Creating the merged file [common-1.8.24.js].
[INFO] Creating the minified file [common-1.8.24.min.js].
Jan 03, 2017 12:03:06 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: [1mcommon-1.8.24.js:5577: [31mERROR[39m - object literals cannot contain duplicate keys in ES5 strict mode[0m
    supportsDataForwarding: function () {
    ^
```

This looks to me like Google Closure is trying to compile using ES5 Strict mode, even though I specified the non-strict `ECMASCRIPT5` mode in my `<closureLanguageOut>` option ([see doc here](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html#closureLanguageOut)). Why is it not disabling strict mode?

Comment: My workaround has been to just fix all the strict mode failures it was complaining about, but I'd still like to know why closure was using strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem and found a way to let the minify-maven-plugin not fail the build in case it complains about ES5 strict mode:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-minify</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>                
            <closureWarningLevels>
                <es5Strict>OFF</es5Strict>
            </closureWarningLevels>
            ...
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>minify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

You may further fine-tune using the following documentation [How to tell closure compiler which warnings you want](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings). Hope this helps :)